# How to get an array of selected row numbers, agnostic of whether the selection is one row, multiple rows, or multiple non-contiguous rows?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I just need to know which rows are in a user's selection when the function is run. They might select one cell, they might drag a selection across multiple cells, or they might ctrl+click multiple cells that aren't next to each other.

But whoever designed Google Apps Script seems to have decided that we're not going to have a consistent way of doing that.

**getActiveRangeList()**

> Return
> RangeList — The list of active ranges.

> If there is a single range selected, this behaves as a getActiveRange() call.

**getActiveRange()**

> Return
> Range — The active range.

**Range** objects have

> getRow() — Returns an integer.
> getLastRow() — Returns an integer.
> getNumRows() — Returns an integer.

**RangeList** objects have

> getRanges() — Returns an array containing each individual range.

I've spent hours reading dozens of articles, essays, and Stack Overflow questions about ranges, and apparently not a single one of them has figured out how to do this simple thing.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation was wrong.

`getActiveRangeList()` does not "behave like `getActiveRange()`" if there is only one range.

`getActiveRangeList().getRanges()` returns an array containing all ranges. If there's only one, then the array has only one range in it.

`getActiveRange().getRanges()` crashes with an error because `getRanges()` doesn't exist in this case.

Therefore, we can just use `getActiveRangeList()` to cover all possible scenarios.

```
function rowChecker()
{
  var active = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRangeList().getRanges();
  for(var n = 0; n < active.length; n++)
  {
    Logger.log(active[n].getRow());
    Logger.log(active[n].getLastRow());
  }
}
```

[image]

```
//3
//3
```

[image]

```
//1
//3
```

[image]

```
//1
//1
//3
//4
```

[image]

```
//1
//1
//2
//3
//4
//4
```

The order the ranges are found seems to depend on the order they were created. For example: If I create that last image starting with the bottom box, then the top box, then the middle two, the output is:

```
//4
//4
//1
//1
//2
//3
```

To get our final array of rows that have a selection in them, we can just modify the code above.

```
function rowChecker()
{
  var rows = [];
  var active = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRangeList().getRanges();
  for(var n = 0; n < active.length; n++)
  {
    for(var r = active[n].getRow(); r <= active[n].getLastRow(); r++)
    {
      if(!rows.includes(r))
      {
        rows.push(r);
      }
    }
  }
  Logger.log(rows);
}
```

[image]

```
//1
//3
//4
```

Be careful: If you don't use that `if(!rows.includes(r))`, you could wind up with something like this, depending on what order the user selects those boxes.

```
//1
//3
//4
//3
//4
```